# Cassandra 3.10 DateTieredCompactionStrategy options for our environment

Tags: cassandra

Our cassandra 3.10 table is operated with the following options. My question is the optimal option value for DateTieredCompactionStrategy for our environment.

- WRITE about 1000 events per second.
- Data is stored for 10 years.
- Queries for recent data and aggregation queries by time window are frequent.
- Updates are not frequent.

Current table options:

```
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'max_sstable_age_days': '365', 'base_time_seconds': '3600', 'max_threshold': '32', 'timestamp_resolution': 'MILLISECONDS', 'enabled': 'true', 'tombstone_compaction_interval': '1', 'min_threshold': '4', 'tombstone_threshold': '.1', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.DateTieredCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 315360000
AND gc_grace_seconds = 60
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0
AND speculative_retry = 'NONE';
```

Please suggest the option.

Answer (score 0):

DTSC have many problems, and this is the cause TWCS was developed.

Please consider moving to this compaction strategy.

Here's an article about TWCS and it's benefits, and also explanation about it's parameters:
http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/12/08/TWCS-part1.html

About your parameters in DTCS:

```
'base_time_seconds': '3600'
```

This can result in a large sstables, if you stay with DTCS, consider lowering it down regarding your record size and throughput.